# How to correctly request location permissions in Android 6.0?

Tags: android, permissions, location, android-6.0-marshmallow

My question: Why is this particular piece of code not requesting permission, and what do I need to do to make it request permission?

I have copied my code directly from Android documentation. It is not working. I have perused probably a dozen similar stack overflow questions. Some of which seem to cite the very code I am using as the correct answer. I cannot see why theirs is working and mine is not. Others which seem to go in totally different directions, but I don't want to follow those because they don't match the documentation I've read.

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="church.eastjordan.circle">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23"
        android:maxSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <uses-permission-sdk-23 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My Code:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    String latitudeString;
    String longitudeString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Awaiting permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "You don't have permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            latitudeString = "No Permission";
            longitudeString = "No Permission";

        }else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "You have permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        UpdateText();


    }

    public void GetLocation(View view) {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        latitudeString = Double.toString(latitude);
        longitudeString = Double.toString(longitude);

        UpdateText();
    }

    public void UpdateText() {

        TextView latView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
        TextView longView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);
        latView.setText( latitudeString);
        longView.setText(longitudeString);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request.
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, my toast messages fire, telling me that I am awaiting permission and that I don't have permission, but no dialog ever opens requesting permission. I expect for a dialog to open requesting permission if I don't already have it.

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

Comment: @sanjeev - Thanks, but I've already tried that also.